# Uninstalled Linux, still getting stuck on "grub" boot menu?

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, grub, boot-partition

I installed then uninstalled Linux on a Windows 10 machine according to instructions at (http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/). I removed the Linux partition (I think) and ran the recovery disk repair utility and ran bootrec/fixmbr, but it is still booting the the "grub" menu and I need to "exit" that, then it boots to Windows.

Is the 260 Healthy (EFI System Partition) my Linux grub thing and do I need to remove that partition (see image) or is something else going on or is there some other way to force it to boot directly to Windows?

After I "exit" the grub menu  get this menu, again this is after running bootrec /fixmbr

[My current Disk Partitions and the menu I get after "exit" grub menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS3IB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the 260 Healthy (EFI System Partition) my Linux grub thing and do I need to remove that partition

No. Don't remove that partition. Windows also puts its bootloader there (see UEFI, especially [here](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) if you want the in-depth details). UEFI is designed to allow OSes to put multiple bootloaders on the system without directly clashing with each other, and then the UEFI firmware presents its own manager to choose between them.

GRUB most likely wasn't actually removed and is additionally the first in the preference list, as can be seen in your photo.

The preferences are controlled from your motherboard firmware. Go into your BIOS/UEFI menu (`del` or `F2` or `Esc` at boot) and change the boot order so the Windows entry is first.

If you really want, you can then go in and delete GRUB from that partition - but don't remove the entire partition or the BOOTMGR (Windows) loader! You could also just leave it there - as long as Windows is first in the list it shouldn't hurt to leave it.